# Rendering animation doesn't work?

Tags: rendering, animation

My animation for some reason doesn't render anymore; instead I just get this black picture. It worked fine a few hours ago, so I'm quite confused.
My settings haven't changed since then.

[image]
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file since you didn't give us any useful settings/information what you have done. thx.

Comment: I cannot see your camera in the screenshot, and what your viewport shows is not the view from the camera - so is it even pointing in the right direction to render the scene? Maybe you accidentally moved or rotated it away.